# Isn't OAuth2 for authentication?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I don't quite figure out why oauth2 is for autheorization and OpenID Connect is for authentication purposes.

From [OAuth2 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.1)

> authorization server
> The server issuing access tokens to the client after successfully
> **authenticating** the resource owner and obtaining authorization.

By other hand, according [Authorization Code Flow RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1) Agent or relying party is redirected to a some kind of authentication page in order to be able to authentication user, doesn't it?

Moreover, I've always read that OpenID Connect in built on Oauth2 in order to provide authentication mechanism to Oauth2. Is it right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OAuth2.0 is an authorization protocol. OpenID Connect incorporates id tokens to add authentication on top of it

> authorization server The server issuing access tokens to the client after successfully authenticating the resource owner and obtaining authorization.

Here the authentication is done for the authorization server, not for the relying party. Authorization needs to identify the end user and for that only the authentication used.

Once the authorization server authenticates the end user, it sends back access token which can be used to communicate with a protected endpoint. And the access token authorizes the relying party to use the protected service.

Access tokens never say anything about the end user. They are opaque to the RP and can only be consumed by the authorization server. But id token is a JWT with end user details. That's why I said OpenID Connect provides authentication.

**How to choose between OAuth2.0 and OpenID Connect ?**

There are many facts you need to consider. Which include the question of "does identity provider support protocols?". But, it all boils down to the fact of how you consume tokens.

If your client application simply allows the end user to consume protected endpoints and does not bother about their identity details, you should use OAuth2.0.

But if your client application is concerned about identifying end user and authenticating them(think about client application's other functionalities such as a database call or even a welcome message which require those) then you should use OpenID Connect.

Comment: So, the only difference is that OpendId Connect provides a layer which provide user information? It seems a very slight protocol purpose, doesn't it?

Comment: @Jordi Well yes and no. Providing user information must do in a proper protected way. That's why there is a dedicated protocol for this purpose (OpenID Connect). With all the validations and mechanisms in place.

Comment: Ok, should I as a developer that's trying to create a platform (with rest API services) to implement OpenId Connect? Or it's enought only to implement OAtuh2? Up to now, I've only implemented OAuth2 in order to protect my APIs, however, I've never felt confortable with "sign up", "log in", "log out" and "sign out" actions. Are these actons related with OAuth2 or are these more close to OpenId Connect?

Comment: @Jordi I updated the answer with protocol selection information. And note that, signup is out of scope for any of the protocol. Login and Logout can be common for both .! What differ are the tokens the login operation produce